# Linux for girlfriend

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

I want to install Linux on my girlfriend's machine. Her current system, Windows Vista, is about 7-8 years old and pretty slow.
She used Windows all her life and to make the change as easy as possible, I'm looking for the most user friendly and windows-like Linux.
I personally use Ubuntu, but she doesn't like the taskbar to be on the left...
I think Linux Mint would be a good idea, but there are several version, like Cinnamon, MATE etc.

What distribution should I take so that afterwards she won't say "I told you, installing Linux was a bad idea!"?

Comment: She'll say "I told you so" no matter what you'll install, people have a tendency to forget past difficulties and think things are worse now than they were before.

Comment: David's comment is 110% on the mark. My wife/kids will love Ubuntu then hate it and say why can't it work like X in Windows. I then remind them about Y & Z in Windows that they hated, and then they tell me to shut up 8-). Pick one and go with it.

Answer (score 2):

[Zorin](http://www.zorin-os.com/) is made specifically for your scenario. On an older machine you'll probably want their lightweight variant. But have you considered Lubuntu or Xubuntu? Both of these are based on Ubuntu so you'll feel more at home with how they work. Personally, I like XFCE for older machines, which is what Xubuntu uses. But a lot of people recommend LXDE, which is what Lubuntu uses. Both can be configured to look very familiar to Windows users.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [OpenSUSE](http://software.opensuse.org/131/en) with KDE as desktop. It is more user friendly for users who are migrating from windows. OpenSUSE is also good in resolving hardware driver issues.

The software installation part is also quite simple to use. OpenSUSE is also good with interfacing printers and scanners.